# Remove the word Kapitel (chapter) from the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to remove the word `Kapitel` (chapter) from the header. I want to display only the number of the chapter and the name.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}

\input{vorlage.tex}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{document}

%% TITLESEITE %%
 \Title
      {Test1}   
      {Test2}   
      {xy}                           
      {zz}                            
      {zz}                               
      {test}                       
      {test}                      
      {17. Oktober 2021}     
\clearpage
%% INHALT %% 

\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{\abstractname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}
\markboth{\abstractname}{}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%% TEXT %%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

vorlage.txt

```
\newcommand{\Title}[8]{


\begin{titlepage}
    
    
        \normalfont \normalsize 
        \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
        
        \center
        \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{img/hft.png} \\[4ex]
        {\LARGE \textsc{Title}} \\[4ex]
        {\Large #1 #2}\\
           \vspace*{8ex}
        \HRule \\[0.4cm]
        { \huge \bfseries #3}\\[0.4cm] 
        \HRule \\[1.5cm]
          \vspace*{8ex}
        {\Large #4\\
                #5\\}

    \vspace*{16ex}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\large
        Betreuung: \\
        #6 \\
        #7 \\
        \vspace*{4ex}
        #8 \\}
    \end{flushleft} 
        
        
    
        
    \end{titlepage}


}
```

What I have

[image]

What I want

[image]

What I got with @PietervanOostrum

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share `vorlage.tex` . Deleting `\input{vorlage.tex}` from your code the output is what you want.

Comment: @SimonDispa i added it to my question

Comment: `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}}`

Comment: @PietervanOostrum thank you! But that don't work. :(

Comment: @PietervanOostrum When I post your code snippet under ` \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}} \pagestyle{plain}` , the correct header is displayed. However, I get 51 errors and before each chapter it says in small lof

Comment: Sorry about that; there was a missing brace pair:
`\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}`

Comment: @PietervanOostrum thank you very much! I really appreciate it. That worked. Perfectly! :)